# Specify field names when mapping List<KeyValuePair> in Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

I have been getting results out of Dapper as a Dictionary:

```
  using (var multi = cnn.QueryMultiple("dbo.[s_Dashboard_stats]", 
     commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure))
  {
    var recentHits =
        multi.Read().ToDictionary(x => (string)x.URL, x => (double)x.MinsAgo);
  }
```

This was working fine but a change in the data has led (correctly) to duplicate key values. To get around this I thought I'd change the dictionary to a List instead:

```
var PopularHits =
    multi.Read<KeyValuePair<string, double>>().ToList<KeyValuePair<string, double>>();
```

The list ends up with items but the values of the KVP are null, how do I project the values into the KeyValuePair objects? I can't seem to get the lambda syntax correct.....

Comment: @lazyberezovsky `multi` is the multi-grid reader returned from `QueryMultiple` - although it has to be noted that when reading a single grid, this is unnecessary - this query could be read with `Query`

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks, Marc. Haven't used multi grid readers yet

Comment: @lazyberezovsky you only need them if your query contains multiple `select`s - which can be useful i.e. `select * from Customers where Id=@id; select * from Orders where CustomerId=@id; select * from CustomerAddresses where CustomerId=@id;` (or whatever)

Comment: This is the case here, there are actually multiple SELECT s which I omitted from the sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
multi.Read()
    .Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, double>((string) x.URL, (double) x.MinsAgo)
    .ToList();
```